# Using Thread or Delay in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, multithreading, delay

I have two classes, the first class's used to call the second class

FIRST CLASS

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Menu Item selected " + item);
    if (item == A) {
        SecondClassVariabel.setViewMode(SecondClass.Object_1);
    } else if (item == B) {
        SecondClassVariabel.setViewMode(SecondClass.Object_2);
    }
```

SECOND CLASS

```
public SecondClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Holder = getHolder();
    Holder.addCallback(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    SecondClassVariabel = Object_1;
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    (new Thread(this)).start();
}

protected Bitmap processFrame(byte[] data) {
    mYuv.put(0, 0, data);
    final int viewMode = Tampilan;

    switch (viewMode) {
    case Object_1:
        /** Call another sub class */
        break;
    case Object_2:
        /**Call another sub class */
        break;
```

============================================================================

the program above has worked successfully
now i'm trying to call "Object_1" and "Object_2" automatically..

*fyi = To call object_1 and object_2, i use button.

I want to add Thread function or Delay function to call object_1 first then object_2 without using button.

The Code...

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    (new Thread(this)).start();
```

and then `(new Thread(this)).sleep(5000);` //for object_1
and then `(new Thread(this)).sleep(5000);` //for object_2
    }

I'm confused with the following step in using delay or threade function..
please help..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but if you want to call both the objects with different threads and having some delay in between then you can do something like this:

1.call object1 in new thread

2.delay - Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);

3.call object2 in new thread

Putting your both the threads to sleep will not help.

Comment: My question= How to set delay time to call object_1 and it will switch to object_2 right after object_1 is being executed?
object 1 >> executing.. (for 5 secs) then 
object 2 >> executing right after object_1 (for 5 secs) ?